# Event Handler Null

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, event-handling

In the `MainWindow` constructor, I am registering an event handler:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        pageViewDocText = new PageViewDocText();
        framePageDocFieldDetail.Content = pageViewDocText;
        pageViewDocText.NewPageIRPRO += new GabeLib.SearchCls.DocEventHandler(ViewIPRO);
    }

    protected void ViewIPRO(string IRPOlink) // ...
}

public partial class PageViewDocText : Page, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event GabeLib.SearchCls.DocEventHandler NewPageIRPRO;

    private void btn_PageBreakNext(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // this fires but NewPageIRPRO is null
        if (NewPageIRPRO != null)
        {
            NewPageIRPRO("dummylink");
        }
    }
}
```

But in `PageViewDocText`, `NewPageIRPRO` is null

What am I doing wrong?
From `PageViewDocText`, I want to call `MainWindow.ViewIPRO`.

This event handler fires and is registered the line below pageViewDocText.NewPageIRPRO +=

```
App.StaticGabeLib.Search.NewDocIRPRO += new GabeLib.SearchCls.DocEventHandler(ViewIPRO);
```

Comment: Does the `PageViewDocText` constructor fire that event?  This is simple to debug; just look at the call stack.  There's no way that the event is null after the subscription unless you have left out the offending code.

Comment: I think you need to show us the line of code where you pick up `NewPageIRPRO` being null.

Comment: @EdS. No a button event handler fires that event.  I am lost as to  why the event handler is empty also.  In GabeLib (a pure class) I use event handler what seems to be the same way and it works fine.

Comment: @retailcoder It is in a button event handler.  Code is posted.

Comment: @Blam, try implementing [add/remove](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc713642.aspx) pattern for `NewPageIRPRO` event and set breakpoins inside to see what's going on.

Comment: Added a check for if NewPageIRPRO exists in a commonly used method.  On some calls it exists and on some calls it does not.   That method is used by some event handlers.  What I suspect in an event handler is registered before NewPageIRPRO is assigned.  Still looking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are calling an event from another class (not listed) and there is a missing delegate.

Try this code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        pageViewDocText = new PageViewDocText();
        framePageDocFieldDetail.Content = pageViewDocText;
        pageViewDocText.PageBreakNext += new PageBreakNext(ViewIPRO);
    }

    protected void ViewIPRO(string IRPOlink) // ...
}

public partial class PageViewDocText : Page, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public delegate void PageBreakNext(string IRPOlink);
    public event PageBreakNext PageBreak;

    private void btn_PageBreakNext(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // this fires but NewPageIRPRO is null
        if (PageBreak != null)
        {
            PageBreak("dummylink");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't follow. btn_PageBreakNext is an event handler for a button on the page and is not called by any page or class.

Comment: I created a sample project with the event delegate created in another class similar to your code and it always seems to work. So, I think your code is correct. Since NewPageIRPRO is null that indicates to me that it might be a different instance of PageViewDocText and not the same instance created by MainWindow. I suggest placing the DocEventHandler delegate in PageViewDocText's constructor. e.g. PageViewDocText(SearchCls.DocEventHandler NewPageIRPRO) { this.NewPageIRPRO = NewPageIRPRO; }. This should prevent any instance from getting created without the handler.

Comment: Still working on it. And I agree with you comments.  It does appear that there are two PageViewDocText objects out there.  Placing the DocEventHandler in the ctor would fix that but I want to figure out why there are two.

Comment: That frame source was also bound in XAML. I had taken out XAML source and it was gone for a while but some how it did not stick.  The button event was firing on the XAML source that did not have the event handler.  Let me verify before I give you the check.  And thanks.  What is strange is the ctor was not firing twice.

Comment: Not technically the answer but lead me to the answer.